# I am unable to make willPopScope work in my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I have a Flutter that users log in with Google accounts and this is handled in my main.dart. If a user is logged in they will be redireted to HomeScreen via loggedInRoute, and otherwise to LoginScreen via loggedOutRoute.

In my HomeScreen I have a ListView.builder that user can tap items and be shown the content.

I want back button to have the same function of my back arrow in the app bar which Flutter has added it automatically in the app bar of the scaffold of the detailed view of my items, but when viewing the content of an entry, when I tap the back button of my smartphone it exits the app instead of going back to the home where I have the list view builder. My project is a biography app that works just like a dictionary app.

## Here is my main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:routemaster/routemaster.dart';

import 'package:zeetionary/firebase/core/common/error_text.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/firebase/core/common/loader.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/firebase/features/auth/controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/firebase/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/router.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/theme/pallete.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(
      widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding); 
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends ConsumerState<MyApp> {
  UserModel? userModel;

.  void getData(WidgetRef ref, User data) async {
    userModel = await ref
        .watch(authControllerProvider.notifier)
        .getUserData(data.uid)
        .first;
    ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => userModel);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialization();
  }

  void initialization() async {
    print('ready in 2...');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('ready in 1...');
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print('go!');
    FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ref.watch(authStateChangeProvider).when(
          data: (data) => MaterialApp.router(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Biography App',
            theme: ref.watch(themeNotifierProvider),
            routerDelegate: RoutemasterDelegate(
              routesBuilder: (context) {
                if (data != null) {
                  getData(ref, data);
                  if (userModel != null) {
                    return loggedInRoute;
                  }
                }
                return loggedOutRoute;
              },
            ),
            routeInformationParser: const RoutemasterParser(),
          ),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
          loading: () => const Loader(),
        );
  }
}
```

## Here is my home screen that have two items in bottom navigation bar

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/constants.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/home/drawers/community_list_drawer.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/theme/pallete.dart';

class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  int _page = 0;

  void displayDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      _page = page;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentTheme = ref.watch(themeNotifierProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        title: const BiographyAppbar(),
        leading: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () => displayDrawer(context),
          );
        }),
      ),
      body: Constants.tabWidgets[_page],
      drawer: const CommunityListDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        backgroundColor: currentTheme.backgroundColor,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.book), label: ''),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer), label: '')
        ],
        onTap: onPageChanged,
        currentIndex: _page,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BiographyAppbar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BiographyAppbar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) {
        return const LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Color.fromARGB(255, 142, 154, 215),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 84, 84)
          ],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ).createShader(bounds);
      },
      child: const Text(
        'Zeetionary',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24.0, 
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
          color: Colors.white, 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## This is my the content of my first item of bottom navigation bar which has a list view builder with two items

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/dictionary/biography_screen/alphabet/einstein.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/dictionary/biography_screen/alphabet/tesla.dart';

class BiographyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BiographyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BiographyScreen> createState() =>
      _BiographyScreenState();
}

class _BiographyScreenState extends State<BiographyScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final List<String> allbiographyItems = [
    "Einstein",
    "Tesla",
  ];
  List<String> filteredWords = [];
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    filteredWords = List.from(allbiographyItems);
  }

  void filterWords(String query) {
    setState(() {
      filteredWords = allbiographyItems
          .where((word) => word.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  void clearSearch() {
    _searchController.clear();
    filterWords('');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _searchController,
                onChanged: filterWords,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search here',
                  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                    onPressed: clearSearch,
                  ),
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BiographyScreenTwo(
              words: filteredWords,
              onTapWord: (biographyItems) {
                if (biographyItems == "Einstein") {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BiographyTesla(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (biographyItems == "Tesla") {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BiographyEinstein(),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _searchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class BiographyScreenTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> words;
  final Function(String) onTapWord;

  const BiographyScreenTwo({
    Key? key,
    required this.words,
    required this.onTapWord,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: words.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTileBiography(
            biographyItems: words[index],
            onTap: () {
              onTapWord(words[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListTileBiography extends StatelessWidget {
  final String biographyItems;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  const ListTileBiography({
    Key? key,
    required this.biographyItems,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: ListTile(
        key: key,
        title: Text(biographyItems),
        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const CardButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      child: Card(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: onPressed,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## This is my tab bar view for Einstein item. It has two tabs

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zeetionary/home/screens/home_screen.dart';
class EinsteinBiography extends StatelessWidget {
  const EinsteinBiography({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const BiographyAppbar(),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, top: 4, right: 14, bottom: 4),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Einstein', 
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: const [
                  UkIconForTab(),
                ],
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(110, 162, 239, 20),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                ),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    EinsteinBiographyTwo(),
                    EinsteinBiographyTwo(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EinsteinBiographyTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const EinsteinBiographyTwo({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('''
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa


aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
'''),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class UkIconForTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const UkIconForTab({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Tab(
      icon: Image.asset(
        'assets/images/uk_one.png',
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried all the ways suggested on the documentation and previous answers here, for example wrapping my scaffold or DefaultTabController with willPopScope, but it does not work and when I tap back button of the phone it exits. I can make the back button of the app bar show AlertDialog or block the button altogether, but I can not make the phone's back button behave like it.